# Why my Wpf application (on full software mode) runs slowly on Citrix server

Tags: wpf, citrix

I've WPF application. Because our Citrix doesn't have a independant graphic carte. I've to set RenderMode en Software only with :

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

It runs still fluently in my sony duo 13:

```
Windows 8.1;
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz (4 CPUs), ~1.6GHz
8192MB RAM
Intel(R) HD Graphics Family; 1792 MB approx memory total;
DirectDraw speedup activated; Direct3D speedup activated; AGP texture activated
```

But it runs bad on Citrix server (only one application executed):

```
Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64 bits (6.1m version 7601)
VMware Virtual Platform
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU x5670 @ 2.93GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.9GHz
4096MB RAM
No graphic carte info
```

I proved my application was running on mode Software with using Windows Performance Tools, all my window of my application is colored by purple tint (it means draw software rendering)

Except Graphic Carte, our Citrix server is more powerful than my hyperbook Sony, but why it works bad?

Thanks

Comment: WPF is not intended to be used on remote desktop type of stuff. Make sure whatever software you're using is compatible with WPF. And switching to `SoftwareOnly` is a terrible idea. Get a proper machine to run the WPF application on instead.

Comment: @HighCore  Hi, i need to have a good reason to persuade my boss. And at this moment, no other proper machine to run the WPF. He enforced me to find a solution for that. Do you have any idea that i can persuade my boss? Any link which can help me?

Comment: Is there official information from Citrix saying they support / don't support WPF?

Comment: No, it supports WPF. I'm runing my application in a Remote Desktop. I has the same issue. Because of latency and the high UI refresh. I'm testing my manager with WPF performance Profiling Tools. I've a good performance schema (Only frame rate and Dirty Rect Additional Rate is refreshed). It means my application has already eliminated all unnecessary UI refresh @HighCore

Comment: In my test remote desktop, event Console.Writeline() output is much slower than local output speed. 4 times slower than local ouptut

Comment: I'm using DevExpress's GridControl. I don't know if it's because their problem.

Comment: A good news, i didn't change my program, but it runs well after serveral manip on the server by my boss. He said he did nothing special...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your Sony doesn't have to send all the graphical updates over the network to another machine. The network kills graphical performance when you're remoting applications. This is particularly noticeable when using mobile devices which are using 3G or WIFI since the latency is quite high. Every single graphical update your app makes is encoding into a JPEG and then sent over the wire to the receiver. So you're looking at 10's if not 100's of ms for updates to be seen on the client depending on network conditions.

Performance for graphically intensive apps is getting better on Citrix. Later versions of the server/receiver support H264 encoding which improves performance considerably, e.g.

http://blogs.citrix.com/2013/11/06/go-supersonic-with-xendesktop-7-x-bandwidth-supercodecs/

Other technology like Framehawk is also being integrated in the Citrix stack which improves performance in poor network conditions:

http://blogs.citrix.com/2014/01/08/framehawk-will-take-our-hdx-technology-to-the-limit/

Comment: Thanks, i found what it was which cause the bad performance. But your information of Citrix helped me a lot

Comment: @BoHU We have similar issues with performance of WPF over Citrix but works great locally. Can you please share your findings on how to improve the performance?

Comment: @donovan Sorry to dig up this old discussion, but would you say that the issue of network being the bottleneck is exacerbated over WPF compared to say WinForms, or is this a problem for Citrix applications in general?

Comment: @RuneAamodt a bit of both. Back when bandwidth was low HDX used a bunch of optimisation at the Windows control level (e.g. local text echo would detect text input controls). As bandwidth has improved increasingly the HDX stack has moved towards video streaming style techniques like using H264. I don't work for Citrix anymore so I'm not really across what the HDX stack is doing lately.